# How to decode this type argument in getopt -F "P:"bala sudheer""

Tags: java, getopt

Actually in my program i should give arguments like `-F "P:"vala sudher""` to search pattern for vala sudher and it is not working for `-F option` i m getting option argument value as only `P:` not whole string , but if i use `-F "P:\" vala sudheer\""`, it is working .  is there any other way around to get parsed through getopt having arguments like that

Comment: If your program parsed options the way you expect it to, it would severely violate convention. Ask yourself if you really want your program to interpret quotes differently than every other program. That is not to mention that globbing will give confusing results to your users.

Comment: I am using getOpt.getOptarg() method

Comment: It seems you don't understand how quote characters are expected to work.